# Is a double complex commutative or anti-commutative?

Tags: homological-algebra

The definition of a double complex on Weibel's *an Introduction to Homological Algebra* is

> ...... the maps $d^h$ go horizontall, the maps $d^v$ go vertically, and eah square anticommutes.

While that on nLab is

> ......each row and each column is a complex  and such that all the squares commute.

I am a bit comfused. Which one is the standard version or are they both fine?

Comment: I think the anticommuting convention is more common. Always check.

Comment: They are used interchangeably, so always double check which one is the one being used.